# Django | InconsistentMigrationHistory: admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency users.0001_initial

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Al migrar, parece que hay algún problemas de migraciones tras crear Users importando (AbstractBaseUser). He borrado migraciones que daban problema, una **vez makemigrations no daba errores, tras hacer migrate me devuelve el siguiente error:**

Error:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency users.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

Parece que queda alguna migración por borrar correspondiente a admin. **¿Dónde se situa admin.0001_initial para poder borrarlo?** Parece que no es de una aplicación creada, sino, una propia de Django. (No estoy seguro).

Gracias.

Comment: En [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651760/django-db-migrations-exceptions-inconsistentmigrationhistory), hay varias respuestas de como solucionarlo.

Comment: Gracias Julio Cesar. Entre las soluciones parece que la aceptada dice de hacer Truncate. Tras hacer truncate makemigrations no da error, pero tras migrate me devuelve: "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: la relación «django_content_type» ya existe" ¿También debería hacer truncate con ésta tabla? Gracias una vez más Julio Cesar.